# Scheduler with varying time difference

Tags: java, spring, cronexpression

I have created a scheduler with cron expression for every 15 minutes

```
file.schedule=0 0/15 * * * ?
```

and it schedules every 15 minutes

Now I need to change this as it should run:

- every 15 minutes from 12 AM(i.e 00:00) to 9 AM (09:00).
- every one hour from after 9 AM (i.e 9.00) to 11 PM (23:00)

How can I achieve  this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do,

every 15 minutes from 12 AM(i.e 00:00) to 9 AM (09:00).

```
0 0/15 0-9 * * ?
```

every one hour from after 9 AM (i.e 9.00) to 11 PM (23:00)

```
0 0   9-23 * * ?
```

Comment: Can this be achieved in a single expression

Comment: As far as I know you cannot combine the two expressions into one single one.

Comment: Create two schedulers with above expression.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) with [ScheduledFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html)

Detailed [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html) on Timers